# Why can't I access a div via JS in my HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add an image into a div, but for some unknown reason I simply can't access the div via JavaScript.

```js
function redirectToProductPage1() {
  // location.href = '/product';
  const pictureDiv = document.getElementById('productPicture');
  console.log(pictureDiv);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="signOutContainer">
    <div id="helloNameDiv">
      <p id="helloName">hello</p>
    </div>
    <div id="signOutDiv"> <button id="signOutButton">sign out</button> </div>
  </div>
  <div id="productPicture">
    <div id="advertising3"></div>
    <div id="picture">
      <img id="img1" src="" alt="test">
    </div>
    <div id="advertising4"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="priceAndColorsDiv">
    <div class="inputsAndPriceDivs" id="price">
      <p>price</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inputsAndPriceDivs"><input type="color" id="chooseColor"></div>
    <div class="inputsAndPriceDivs"><input type="number" id="productAmount" placeholder="product Amount"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="range" id="chooseSize">
  <div id="description">description</div>
  <div id="addToCartDiv"><button id="addToCartButton">add to cart</button></div>
  <script src='script.js'></script>
</body>
```

As you can see I'm trying to access the `pictureDiv`, but when I print it, I get null.
When I try to print the first div `signOutContainer` I get the element properly, also every element inside the div prints properly, every single element that comes after that div, will print null, I tried `DOMcontentLoad` to no help, any advice?

Tried `DOMcontentLoad` maybe it didn't load yet or something, tried deleting the first div `signOutContainer` and I still couldn't get the other elements in the html.

Comment: where do you call this function? `redirectToProductPage1`?

Comment: my guess is your code above is not exactly what you have going on.

Answer (score 3):

The correct name of that event is `DOMContentLoaded`, not `DOMcontentLoad`.

Try the following Javascript:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  console.log(document.getElementById('productPicture'));
});
```

In fact, a callback is not needed here since by default the script tag is processed synchronously, so JS code above should work as well (DOM will be ready before JS fires).

Also, do not forget to call your `redirectToProductPage1()` function somewhere.

Comment: Hi, it did not help, i still get null.
ofc i am calling the function on a button. still getting null, im only able to fetch the first div and its children, nothing else from that HTML.

Comment: Well, then check your context (other HTML and JS besides the ones you posted) or libraries you are using, if any. Your HTML and JS from my answer work as intended. Here is the proof: https://jsfiddle.net/yctnmg0k/ (you will see the HTML element printed in the console once you run it). In fact, a callback is not needed here since by default the `script` tag is processed synchronously, so JS code you provided should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the JavaScript code is executing before the HTML elements are fully loaded and as a result, the productPicture div may not yet exist when the code runs. One way to solve this is by wrapping the JavaScript code inside a DOMContentLoaded event listener, like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const pictureDiv = document.getElementById('productPicture');
  console.log(pictureDiv);
});
```

This ensures that the JavaScript code runs only after the HTML content has been fully loaded. Another thing you can try is moving the script tag to the end of the body element, just before the closing  tag. This approach can also help ensure that all of the HTML content has been loaded before the script runs.

Comment: Hi, it did not help, still getting null, im only able to fetch the first div and its children, nothing else from that HTML.

Comment: If the pictureDiv variable is still null, you might want to double-check that the ID attribute of the div is indeed "productPicture" and that there are no syntax errors in your HTML file.

Comment: i shared the entire html file in my question.. there is no error. are answering me with chatGPT lol?

Comment: I'm helping you. you are insulting me. ChatGPT is not available in my country bro.

Comment: I am a traditionally programmer bro.

Comment: ok Surush im sorry for offending you, thanks for offering your help.